# How can the subscribed response return null, if the API is sending a response, in angular?

Tags: angular

[This is the API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEOrR.png)

```
  this._workOrderService
            .downloadFile(dataCont.id, dataCont.pmbypassId, dataCont.filePath, dataCont.displayName, dataCont.mimeType)
            .subscribe(
                event  => {
                    console.log("Response after the API is called =>",event);
                  const blob = new Blob([event], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
                  console.log(blob);
                  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  const link = document.createElement('a');
                  link.href = url;
                  link.download = dataCont.filePath;
                  link.click();
                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

This is how I am handling the response for the API but the "event" is null here. What could be the reason for this?

I was expecting the contents of the response sent by the API and the response to not be null.

Comment: when you open the network tab in the devtools - do you see the outgoing request coming back with the data?

Comment: No it did not. But I have solved the error now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The observable in my service class was "void", so I changed that to "any". That solved the problem for me.
Observable void  to Observable any.